# Is there any specific function to choose max words in R?

Tags: r

For e.g.,

Cuisines

1. Indian, American, Japanese, Korean, Chinese
2. Meditterranean, Continental, Indonesian
3. Malaysian, Mexican, Brazillian, Vietnamese

Restaurants

1. A
2. B
3. C

How can I find out which restaurant serves more cuisines? Is there any function to get this done? I want to get both the restaurant's and the cuisine's names. Please help.

I tried to use the count function, but it's not showing the desired result.

Comment: max word means "counting occurence of each label" ?

Comment: have u tried `group_by` and `arrange` with `count` or `summarize`

Comment: Could you clarify what your data look like? Is it a vector, data frame, etc?

Answer (score 1):

If your data look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(cuisines = c("Indian, American, Japanese, Korean, Chinese",
                              "Meditterranean, Continental, Indonesian",
                              "Malaysian, Mexican, Brazillian, Vietnamese"),
                 Restaurants = LETTERS[1:3])
```

In base R, you can use `gregexpr` and `\\W+` to count the words, then use `which` with `max` to index (I also added a `stringr` package option)

```
wds <- lengths(gregexpr("\\W+", df$cuisines))
# or stringr::str_count(df$cuisines, "\\S+")

df[which(wds == max(wds)), ]

#                                      cuisines Restaurants
# 1 Indian, American, Japanese, Korean, Chinese           A
```